# Where can I get FlexUnit

Tags: unit-testing, apache-flex, flexunit4

Simple question, where do I actually download the FlexUnit binary? I've found:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/FlexUnit+Getting+Started

and

https://github.com/flexunit/flexunit

The links on the first go to www.flexunit.com which doesn't appear to exist.

The second has all the source code, but no build instructions.

Answer (score 2):

FlexUnit donation to Apache Flex is currently in progress and has yet to be formulated into a release. Meanwhile you can find a nightly build at https://builds.apache.org/job/flex-flexunit/ws/ (flexunit-*.zip).

**Update**

An official release can now be downloaded at: 
http://flex.apache.org/download-flexunit.html

Comment: Can't really afford to deal with a nightly build. Was really hoping for a release, even one pre-Apache. Is there someplace that I can get a timeline?

Comment: I just made a release candidate for 4.2.0 so hopefully we have an official Apache release in a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Maven to get access to Flexunit like in this question here:
[How do I get Flexunit, FlexMojos and Mockolate to work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505129/how-do-i-get-flexunit-flexmojos-and-mockolate-to-work-together)

Or you can download flexunit from various open source projects like here:
https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/build/libs